# The linear program for widest path or maximum capacity path problem.

Tags: linear-programming

I have to give the linear program for the widest path problem or maximum capacity path problem which gives the path where the greatest flow is achieved. I thought of solving it as a Max Min problem. First to find all edges that have the minimum value in each possible path from source to destination and second to find the maximum of these values. I don't know how to implement the first part as a linear program. Can anyone help me?
If there is another way to solve the problem I will be grateful to know.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why it is necessary to find all edges that have the minimum value in each possible path from source to destination?

Comment: For effective combinatorial solutions see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem

Comment: @callculus Because I have to find the maximum of these minimums and I have to consider all these edges. If my idea of solving this problem is wrong, please correct me.